# Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: PDFJS only with Opera

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I use pdfjs imported as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js"></script>
```

I have script for rendering PDFs to canvas:

```
function renderPDF(url, canvas_name, scale) {
    function renderPage(page) {
        var canvas = $("#"+canvas_name)[0];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / page.getViewport(scale).width);
        var renderContext = {

          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport
        };

        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        page.render(renderContext);
    }
    function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
        pdfDoc.getPage(1).then(renderPage);
    }
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);
};
```

It works perfectly with Chrome and Firefox. But with Opera, I am getting following error

```
Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: PDFJS
```

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Now I notice, that in Firefox I am getting following error form pdf.js in console (although it works as expected):

```
Error: Invalid parameter in getDocument, need either Uint8Array, string or a parameter object
```

Comment: You should not load pdfJS directly from GitHub - it is not a CDN. Download it to your server or find a CDN

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, now it throws no error. But does not work neither. I will update the question.

Comment: Please note that OPERA includes pdfjs as a renderer. Perhaps there is a conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved when I download the pdfjs and use it locally, as mplungjan suggested.

Furthermore, it was necessary to load more files in template exactly in this order:

```
<script src="js/pdfjs/web/compatibility.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdfjs/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js"></script>
```